# Change a British Summer Time date to a GMT date

Tags: javascript

I've tried various javascript methods for dealing with UTC including what I've seen on stackoverflow but none work on this particular example:

```
 var newDate = new Date("Wed Apr 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)");
 console.log(newDate);
 console.log(new Date(newDate.toGMTString()));
```

The output of both is:

```
Wed Apr 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
Wed Apr 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

Comment: When you `console.log()` a `Date` instance, it's always going to present the locale-specific string version (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString). Try `console.log(newDate.toUTCString())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new Date to log over the formatted one, just remove the new instance creation to see the GMT Time.

```
 var newDate = new Date("Wed Apr 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)");
 console.log(newDate.toGMTString());
```

Anyway `toGMTString()` method is deprecated, you should use `toUTCString()` instead.